# Angular UI ng-grid binding to $resource

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angularjs-resource

I'm trying to bind data to the angular-ui ng-grid using a $resource but something isn't working - the options are being applied to the grid and the directive is working as I can see the column headers but there is no data

Service/factory

```
angular.module('app').factory('mvVegetableService',function($resource){
    var myVegetableResource = $resource('/api/vegetable/:_id', {_id:"@id"}, {
        update: {method:'PUT', isArray: false}
    });

    return myVegetableResource;

});
```

Controller

```
angular.module('app').controller('mvVegetableCtrl', function($scope, mvVegetableService){
   $scope.vegetableService = mvVegetableService.query();
   $scope.dataVegetables = {};
   $scope.vegetableGridOptions = {
      data: $scope.dataVegetables,
      columnDefs:[{
         field: "colorCode",
         displayName: "Color Code"
      }]
   };
   $scope.vegetableService.$promise.then(function(vegetables){
      $scope.dataVegetables = vegetables;

      console.log(vegetables);
      // this outputs 
      // 0: Resource
          // expanded
             // $$hashKey: "00D"
             //       __v: 0
             //       _id: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
             // colorCode: "GREEN"
      // 1: Resource
      // $promise: Object
          // expanded
            // catch: function (callback) {
            // finally: function (callback) {
            // then: function (callback, errback, progressback) {
            // __proto__: Object
            // $resolved: true
            // length: 2
      // $resolved: true
      // length: 2
      // __proto__: Array[0]
   });
});
```

On the same page/controller I'm able to ng-repeat for options in a select element and it works fine.

Comment: Um... Is all this in the correct order? Why the service is called after the ng-grid options? ... $scope.dataVegetables = {};
   $scope.vegetableGridOptions = {
      data: $scope.dataVegetables, ... looks like you're passing an empty object as data, and that you are populating it afterwards.

Comment: That seems to be the pattern of how I've seen this grid bound in other posts. I'm pretty sure its in the correct order so long as the variable exists (even empty) when the grid is created

Comment: Have you tried without a $promise? Or rather what's the content of the returned $promise object?

Comment: I've edited the post to show 'expanded' versions of what is in the returned object - The returned $promise object is 'standard' - I'm able to 'bind' to a select element using the exact same code and an ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell ng-grid's `data` property needs to be a string.  So instead of:

```
data: $scope.dataVegetables
```

Try:

```
data: "dataVegetables"
```